# How to wait for the recursive loop to finish and display the message?

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I'm running a recursive function with setTimeout, what I've noticed is that javascript goes straight through the wait() function and doesn't wait for it to finish. It goes right through and leaves the wait() method working by itself.

```js
wait(100, 30)

function wait(time, limit) {
    console.log('value >> ' + limit)
    if (limit < 0) return 'success'
    setTimeout(function () {
        wait(time, --limit)
    }, time)
}

console.log('hi')
```

Note that my "hi' message is at the top when running the script, because it went straight through without waiting for the recursive loop. My "hi" message should be at the end.

Can anyone help me leave the hi message at the end after running all the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handover a function which is called at the end of waiting.

```js
function wait(time, limit, fn) {
    console.log('value >> ' + limit)
    if (limit < 0) return fn();
    setTimeout(function () {
        wait(time, --limit, fn);
    }, time)
}

function sayHi() { console.log('hi'); }

wait(100, 30, sayHi);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Besides calling the sayHi() function is it possible to somehow wait for the loop without going through and not call any functions?

Comment: no, it is not possible to pause the execution.

Answer (score 0):

you can also simply return the message which do you want:

```
wait(100, 30);

function wait(time, limit) {
  console.log("value >> " + limit);
  if (limit < 0) return console.log("hi");
  setTimeout(function () {
    wait(time, --limit);
  }, time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Nina*'s approach and also for use cases where a callback can not be implemented as easily as demonstrated with *Nina*'s example code, one might use an abstraction for it, which for JavaScript is [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s.

Here, instead of 30 times delaying for 100 milliseconds until logging, one would implement `wait` as promise which resolves after 3 seconds with the additional logging provided as *thenable* ...

```js
const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

wait.then(() => console.log('hi'));

console.log({ wait: String(wait) });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```